# Provider in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to java and trying to run sample programs using JPA. Code is getting compiled successfully, but when I run it, it is failing with below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No     Persistence provider for EntityManager named FirstProject:  The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

    at      javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:154)
    at  javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at com.infybank.services.AccountDS.main(AccountDS.java:35)
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly is provider in persistence.xml and how to decide what should be provided. Thanks in Advance.

Below is what I provided in persistence.xml (I got it from a sample training material)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="FirstProject">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider</provider>
<class>com.infybank.entities.Account</class>

<properties>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testdb"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
<property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.read-connections.max" value="1"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.write-connections.max" value="1"/>
<property name="toplink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/>
<property name="toplink.logging.level" value="SEVERE" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the toplink-essentials.jar in your classpath? Its the one that includes you oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider package...

Comment: I have that .jar file under path "D:\Docs\Tutorials\Java Tutorials\3 -- Oracle JPA\Required JAR and XML Files". So I added below to my classpath. Is that correct?
    "D:\Docs\Tutorials\Java Tutorials\3 -- Oracle JPA\Required JAR and XML Files\toplink-essentials.jar"

Comment: I have also added that JAR file under JPALibraries through Build Path -> Add External JARS in eclipse.

Comment: Yes this is the correct way, you might still be missing a jar or your xml configuration is wrong somehow, I would suggest you check out the other similar questions on stackoverflow, there are  lot of them, just search "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named", you'll get pleanty of possible fixes

Comment: I tried running my code in debug mode and it I see that the error is 'Source not found'. The message says that "The JAR file D:\Docs\Tutorials\Java Tutorials\3 -- Oracle JPA\Required JAR and XML Files\javaee.jar has no source attachment".
And it is giving me an option to add source. But I don't know where I can the source from. Please advise.

Comment: This is just a message asking for the source code (jar) location so that Eclipse can show you the lines during debugging, it`s not really relevent to your problem, because it would show you javaee code and thats obviously not the problem...try doing step over and not step into for functions that are not yours...have you tried the various solutions proposed in other similar questions? As a last resort, I would advise you to use another persistence provider, like org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager, personally I never used toplink....

Comment: By the way, where is your persistence.xml file located, is it at the base of WEB-INF? You could try putting it at the base of one of your src folders

Comment: Where is WEB-INF folder located? When I created a project through eclipse, I only got a structure like below
    JPAworkspace\FirstProject\src 
and it has folders "com" which got created while creating a package and the other "META-INF" which is containing persistence.xml file and I changed it with my DB and other details included.

Comment: I changed provider as per your suggestion. But even then the same error. By seeing the error, I could say that it is still referring to old provider. not sure why!!
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named FirstProject:  The following providers:
    oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
    Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.

Comment: You should check out the standard directory structure of a web app, something like this:[link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) , you're supposed to have a WEB-INF folder....and for the other error, I would try cleaning the projet, when theres strange behavior like this a clean usually does the job